# r-xsr won't bind to qx7s

Tags: transmitter, taranis, receiver

I'm trying to bind an r-xsr to a qx7s, but the receiver shows a solid red, green and blue light and won't bind.

I have updated the receiver to version 2.1.0 LBT and the transmitter to the EU version of OpenTX 2.3.7.

Is there a known problem with any of this firmware, or is there another problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I solved it: I had installed the EU version of OpenTX, but I hadn't flashed the internal module on the transmitter. When I did that it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

Another potential cause for not being able to bind is having a different radio firmware on the receiver vs the transmitter module. I recently ran into this issue with some of my setups. The RX was on 2.X.X firmware, which FrSky enabled some minor attempts at encryption to discourage unauthorized receivers and transmitters.  This firmware is NOT backward compatible with the 1.X.X radio firmware, so if your internal module on your transmitter is not updated to 2.X.X firmwares it WON'T bind. You will need to upgrade your internal radio module to the correct firmware as well. You can [find the current 2.X.X firmwares here](https://www.frsky-rc.com/download/) if needed.  Keep in mind if you upgrade you'll need to upgrade ALL your RXs in all your quads, and you won't be able to go back unless you downgrade ALL your RXs and radio firmware again.

Also, it's worth pointing out that for all their struggles, within a few weeks there was an update available for the open-source multi-protocol modules that allows binding to the 2.X.X firmware RXs. So, in the end, they've caused a lot of inconvenience for users and not accomplished their goals.  Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some potential solutions:

- You might have selected the wrong mode, i.e. D8 and D16
- The bind button is damaged on the receiver

Comment: D16 is selected, and the button seems to work as well...

Answer (score 2):

As well as the previously mentioned hardware and mode issues, some people report that having your transmitter too close to your receiver during binding can cause ‘washout’, which prevents binding as the signal is too ‘intense’ (for lack of a better word) to be understood.

I’d try moving your transmitter 1.5m from your receiver and trying again.